# Is there any way to align temporally two signals in spectrogram?

Tags: cross-correlation, stft, correlation

I am keen to know that If I have two signals say :

**Farend_signal (y[n])** and **Nearend_signal (x[n])**

and **x[n]** also contains an **echo of y[n] with some delay**.

Is there any technique to align these two signals temporally is Spectrogram?
For example, any correlation technique to find the temporal displacement between signals after making a spectrogram(STFT) of two signals?

Comment: Techniques you already  know in the time domain for template matching, adapted filtering, echo detection, etc. can be transported in a time-scale or time-frequency domain, where the processing is easier due to better signal separation

Comment: In addition to what Laurent said: note that the spectrogram is usually a power thing and thus "erases" phase information; you can't measure fine temporal shifts of signals in a power description of frequency domain. So, I'll go with: using the spectrogram is not a good method.

Comment: @LaurentDuval  Thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay I got it. Actually, I was following this question [Eliminate Signal A from Signal B] (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/eliminate-signal-a-from-signal-b). But I wasn't able to eliminate the signal completely. So, after analysis, I thought that there might be some temporal displacement between the signals so that's why I thought of this technique.

Comment: I agree with @Marcus. I was just supposing you meant a short-time Fourier transform

Comment: @LaurentDuval Yeah. But I also looked into the techniques you suggested but I want to eliminate y[n] from x[n]  and since I have the echo of y[n] in x[n] I thought there might be some technique if I temporally align the signals in the spectrogram and then eliminate the signal.

Comment: then don't do it on the spectrogram. You can't eliminate echos there, that can't work – there's no phase info.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, if I have detected echo in a precise manner say (i know the chunk of data say 21 ms) of the far-end signal whose echo is present in my near-end signal then still should I have to estimate RIR?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a large number of  "model-based echo suppression" or "adaptive acoustic echo cancellation" (for the keywords). They often combine a sparsifying transformation (wavelets, time-frequency decompositions) and some form of fitting or adaptation of the model to the time and frequency localization where the echo dwells. Underlying hypotheszs are:

- the model somehow looks like the echo,
- the similarity will increase in the transformed domain,
- this representation will help the morphing, or make is more efficient (faster, etc.)

For voice, you find a look of literature, overviews, etc. You may also look at neighboring domains: vibration-based non-destructive testing or monitoring, ultrasounds. I would mention seimic processing, where echoes are sometimes named multiples (waves bounding several times between layers). Here are two examples I have been involved in. A first one quite fast which uses 1-tap adaptive filters (hint: a complex filter), the second  more involved with optimization constraints. They use time-scale wavelets, but could be readily adapted to short-term Fourier transforms or multi-input/multi-output filter banks.

- [Adaptive multiple subtraction with wavelet-based complex unary Wiener filters](http://dx.doi.org/10.1190/geo2011-0318.1), 2012  ([preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4674))
- [A Primal-Dual Proximal Algorithm for Sparse Template-Based Adaptive Filtering: Application to Seismic Multiple Removal](https://doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2014.2331614), 2014 ([preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1081))

[image: Template-based echo suppression in seismic data]